# Spring, component-scan causes FatalBeanException around NamespaceHandler

Tags: java, spring, component-scan

When I use component-scan I get the folowing exception:

```
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler] 
for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context] 
does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1433)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
```

Here is the XML configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="version" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="${project.version}"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="base"/>
```

When I remove the `component-scan` evertying is parsed fine, but obviously this isn't a solution.  What is casuing the problem?

I have read a lot about old version of Spring being on the classpath but I can verify that is not the case.

Here are my dependiences with ${spring.version} being 3.2.5-RELEASE.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Do you have the context-support jar on the classpath?

Comment: I do not, let me add that and see if it works.  Strange that my tests are able to run fine with component-scan but not in the container!

Comment: Another theme for this error is that there is an older version of a spring jar on the classpath.

Comment: I have examined the entire classpath.. there is no other Spring jar on the computer.

Also, adding the Spring context-support didn't work

Comment: There has to be something more to this, the following example works for me: https://gist.github.com/kmb385/9050008

Comment: Stupid question, but you do have a closing `</beans>` tag right?  It is omitted in the provided code.

Comment: Yeah, it is there but stackoverflow isn't showing it for whatever reason!

Thanks for taking such a personal approach Kevin.. you are right.. there has to be something deeper within the container I am using.....

Comment: Further investigation that sure enough, there is a second Spring JAR. 

We are using WebLogic and there is a "repackaged" JAR loaded and hidden... so now I have to work around that.. or not use Autowire!

Comment: Uggg oracle been there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error, but the xml context file being loaded, had a namespace reference to spring-webmvc.  I had forget to add the mvc dependency to my pom file.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by accidentally including Spring deps in a thin war's `WEB-INF/lib`, if the jars are already in the ear's `META-INF/lib`.

This is common if you use maven.